# Pass ILogger<T> to Polly retry policy without HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, ilogger

When making HTTP calls using an instance of `HttpClient` wrapped in Polly's retry policy and injected into a controller using dependency injection, I want to send `ILogger<T>` from the call site to a delegate of the retry policy (e.g., `onRetry`), so logs are registered more appropriately.

[Polly docs explain how to achieve this](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#configuring-httpclientfactory-policies-to-use-an-iloggert-from-the-call-site) by sending `ILogger<T>` from the calls site to the retry delegates leveraging `Context` encapsulated in an `HttpRequestMessage` request.

However, this solution works when you leverage a method of the `HttpClient` that takes `HttpRequestMessage` in one of its overloads. For instance, `client.SendAsync`.

However, not every method of `HttpClient` take `HttpRequestMessage`. For instance, I'm using `client.GetStreamAsync`, which none of its overloads take `HttpRequestMessage`.

In this case, I wonder how you would pass the `Ilogger<T>` to Polly's retry delegates.

Comment: Are you decorating your Typed/named HttpClient with AddPolicyHandler?

Comment: Yes, like `.AddPolicyHandler((provider, _) => { ... here I define a strategy with Policy.WrapAsync });`

Comment: Since you are using this overload you can call the GetRegisteredService on the provider parameter. Shall I post an answer to demonstrate it?

Comment: Thank you, though I am afraid that will not give an `Ilogger<T>` where `T` is the controller where the `HttpClient` is injected.

Comment: So do you want to use the Controller's logger inside the onRetry?

Comment: Correct, similar to how it is done in the linked docs for `SendAsync`, but I am looking for ideally similar behavior for `GetStreamAsync`.

Comment: In this case you have two options. Define the policy inside the controller or inside the PolicyRegistry. In both cases you have to explicitly call ExecuteAsync. Do you want me to post an answer where I demonstrate these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Options that does not work for your use case

#### Using the `Context` object with `HttpRequestMessage`

As you have stated in your question this is not applicable, since you don't have a `HttpRequestMessage` instance on which you could access the `Context` via the `request.GetPolicyExecutionContext` call.

#### Using `AddPolicyHandler` + `IServiceProvider`

The `AddPolicyHandler` has [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which provides access to the `IServiceProvider` and to the `HttpRequestMessage`. You could obtain an `ILoggerFactory` via `provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()` and then you could call `factory.CreateLogger<T>`.

The problem with this approach is that you don't know `T` at policy registration time, since you want to use the Controller as `T`.

### Options that could work for your use case

#### Defining the policy inside your Controller

If you would define the policy inside the same class where you have the intention to use it then you could access the `ILogger<YourController>`.

There are two drawbacks of this approach:

- You have to define (more or less) the same policy in every place where you want to use it
- You have to explicitly call the `ExecuteAsync`

The first issue can be addressed via the `PolicyRegistry`

#### Registering the policy into `PolicyRegistry` and using `Context`

You can register your policy/ies into a [`PolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry) and then you can obtain them (via `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry`) inside your controller. This approach lets you define your policy in the way that you can retrieve an `ILogger` from the `Context` inside the `onRetry`. And you can specify the `Context` when you call the `ExecuteAsync`

```
var context = new Polly.Context().WithLogger(yourControllerLogger);
await policy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct)  => ..., context);
```

#### Registering the policy into `PolicyRegistry` and using `try`-`catch`

The previous approach used the `Context` to transfer an object between the policy definition and its usage. One can say that this separation is a bit fragile since the coupling between these two is not explicit rather via a magic `Context` object.

An alternative solution could be to perform logging only inside your the `ExecuteAsync` to avoid the usage of the `Context`

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(async ()  => 
   try
   {
       ...
   }
   catch(Exception ex) //filter for the retry's trigger exception(s)
   {
       yourControllerLogger.LogError(...);
   });
```

---

As you can see none of the above solutions is perfect since you want to couple the policy and its usage via logging.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> I'm not a big fan of defining policy inside a controller, because I generally reuse a policy (and accordingly the `HttpClientFactory`) in different controllers.

As I said above, this is one option out of three. The other two options do not require you to define your policy inside the controller class. You can define them inside the startup

```
var registry = new PolicyRegistry()
{
    { "YourPolicyName", resilientStrategy }
};
services.AddPolicyRegistry(registry);
```

and then retrieve the given policy inside the controller

```
private readonly IAsyncPolicy policy;
public YourController(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> registry)
{
    policy = registry.Get<IAsyncPolicy>("YourPolicyName"):
}
```

> I suppose there is no other cleaner solution

If you want to / need to use the controller's logger inside the `onRetry` delegate then I'm unaware of any cleaner solution.

If you want to use that logger to be able to *correlate* the controller's log with the policy's log then I would rather suggest to use a **correlation id** per request and include that into your logs. Steve Gordon has a nuget package called [correlationId](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId) which can help you to achieve that.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of defining policy inside a controller, because I generally reuse a policy (and accordingly the `httpclientfactory`) in different controllers. But I suppose there is no other cleaner solution.

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove I've updated my post, please check it.

Comment: Thank you Peter for clarifying that, it is a great suggestion.